# Image map in android. Error: Invalid tag maps

Tags: android, html, xml, maps, imagemap

I'm trying to make an Imagemap in Android. I have made an XML values-file to save the different areas. Here is what I've got in there:

```
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    -->
<maps xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<map name="aspa">
    <area name="kl" shape="rect" coords="1396,897,1472,1016" id="@+id/area0010"/>
    <area name="fj" shape="rect" coords="744,280,820,399" id="@+id/area0050"/>        
    <area name="nu" shape="rect" coords="408,668,484,984" id="@+id/area0075"/>
</map>
</maps>
```

But right now I always get the error "Invalid start tag maps". Here is the code for my attrs xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="ImageMap">
            <attr name="map" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:lol="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/PACKAGE"
android:orientation="vertical"   
android:id="@+id/my_frame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<PACKAGE.Page
android:id="@+id/image1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:src="@drawable/image"
lol:map="aspa"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for the help. :)